# Why is my character stuck in the jump animation?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

My charcter always gets stuck in the jump animation after I press space once. I've searched online and apprently it's because it's not registering my onGround function, which i'm confused on how to do. Any help is appreciated!

Here's my code:

```cs
    public Transform GroundCheckTransform;
    public float GroundCheckRadius;
    public LayerMask GroundMask;

    private Vector3 respawnPoint;
    public GameObject deathBarrier;
    public GameObject enemy;
    public int Respawn;

    private Animator anim;

    Rigidbody2D rb;

    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        respawnPoint = transform.position;
    }

    void Update()
    {
         transform.position += Vector3.right * SpeedValues[(int)CurrentSpeed] * Time.deltaTime;
        
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            if (OnGround())
            {
                rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
                rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * 26f, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
                anim.SetBool("isJumping", false);
            }
            anim.SetBool("isJumping", true);
        }   
    }
    
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
        {
            if(collision.tag == "Barrier")
            {
                transform.position = respawnPoint;
            }
            if (collision.tag == "Enemy")
            {
                transform.position = respawnPoint;
                
            }
            StartCoroutine(WaitBeforeRespawn());

        IEnumerator WaitBeforeRespawn()
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
        }

        if(collision.tag == "End")
        {
           this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
    
    bool OnGround()
    {
        return Physics2D.OverlapCircle(GroundCheckTransform.position, GroundCheckRadius, GroundMask);
        
    }
```

I've been stuck on this issue for 2 days now, and I'm still kind of new to unity, so any help right now is appericated!

Comment: because `anim.SetBool("isJumping", true);` is always executed when pressing space ... and `OnGround()` only if you press space while on the ground ... but as said also is overruled afterwards ... you probably rather want to set it to true where you jump and have your ground check separate

Comment: In general: in makes little sense to mix Rigidbody and `transform.position =` .. this will overrule/clash with the physics ... you will want to either go by physics and then either by `velocity` or `AddForce` ... or do everything yourself via `transform` ... the mix makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

You're only setting the animation to false after checking that the character is on the ground **AND** that the player is holding down the jump key (you're also setting the animation back to true immediately after, regardless). You need to move the animation change to a different conditional. We should also move the inner `OnGround()` check into the same conditional as the Input check because we don't want to perform any action if the player tries to jump in the air (or at least not in this case):

```
bool grounded = OnGround();

// Player is trying to jump AND is on floor.
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && grounded)
    {
        // Jump
        rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * 26f, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        anim.SetBool("isJumping", true);
    }
// Character is Grounded
else if (grounded)
{
    anim.SetBool("isJumping", false); // Reset animation.
}
```

P.S: Thanks to @derHugo for pointing out that calling `OnGround()` twice is an unnecessary performance loss. Another alternative to storing the result of `OnGround()` would be to the jumping conditional within the `OnGround()` check but personally I think the nesting and possible difficulties in tweaking the jumping logic in the future aren't worth the space taken up by a boolean variable.

Comment: You are now executing `OnGround` twice which might be expensive depending on the implementation ... just store the result before the if

Comment: @derHugo Thank you for the suggestion, I completely missed that. Minimizing function calls is definitely a good idea in game code (and other code in most cases).

Answer (score 0):

Pressing Space makes you jump. So if you press space, Grounded will always be false. So checking if your grounded after pressing space will always be false. You can probably do this a much better way inside of the Grounded function:

```
bool OnGround()
{
    // check if on the ground and assign to a temporary variable.
    Collider2D col = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(GroundCheckTransform.position, GroundCheckRadius, GroundMask);
    // if the overlap circle detects the ground, disable the animation.
    if (col != null) anim.SetBool("isJumping", false);
    // return the end result.
    return col;
}
```